# Templating support in GitHub Saved Replies

Tags: github

The new [saved reply](https://github.com/blog/2135-saved-replies) feature in GitHub is handy. I'd like to add a personal touch to my saved replies by inserting the issue author's username into the template. E.g.

```
Hi {{author}},

Blah blah blah...
```

Where `{{author}}` would resolve to the issue author's username (e.g. `@kaycebasques`).

Is this feature supported?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't natively implemented in GitHub, but can be achieved by using [`GitHub Enhanced Comments`](http://samdd.me/r?https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-enhanced-comments/pnjmkbnhcnpbngfdipbfkpclggfhbbgj), a chrome extension on the Chrome web store.

> Possible placeholders are:
>
> **{repo_name}** inserts the name of the repository
>   **{repo_url}**      inserts the full URL of the repository
>   **{author}**         inserts the @name of the author of the issue
>   **{owner}**          inserts the @owner of the repository
>   **{owner_url}**   inserts the full URL of the owner of the repository

Answer (score 0):

Neither https://github.com/blog/2135-saved-replies nor https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-saved-replies/ has any evidence whatsoever of support for such template.

> Is this feature supported?

It seems that answer is "no".